# Node-Red, SQL Server INSERT INTO (columns...) SELECT Columns... FROM OPENJSON({{{payload}}}) WITH

Tags: json, sql-server, node-red

I'm trying to acquire some JSON data from a public APE and insert the records into my SQL Azure database. The API request is working, as is the convert to object in the JSON node but I cannot seam to get the `OPENJSON()` function to parse the json data object properly. I get this error:

> RequestError: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'o' is found at position 1.

The json data acquired from the api is:

```json
{ 
  "data":[{ 
    "from": "2021-09-22T23:00Z",
    "to": "2021-09-22T23:30Z",
    "intensity": {
      "forecast": 105,
      "actual": 91,
      "index": "low"
    }
  },
  { 
    "from": "2021-09-22T23:30Z",
    "to": "2021-09-23T00:00Z",
    "intensity": {
      "forecast": 92,
      "actual": 80,
      "index": "low"
    }
  },
  { 
    "from": "2021-09-23T22:00Z",
    "to": "2021-09-23T22:30Z",
    "intensity": {
      "forecast": 153,
      "actual": null, 
      "index": "low"
    }
  },
  { 
    "from": "2021-09-23T22:30Z",
    "to": "2021-09-23T23:00Z",
    "intensity": {
      "forecast": 150,
      "actual": null, 
      "index": "low"
    }
  }]
}
```

And the SQL Azure node has the following code:

```sql
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{{{payload}}}';

INSERT INTO TCarbonIntensity ([from], [to], [forecast], [actual], [index])
    SELECT [from], [to], [forecast], [actual], [index]
    FROM OPENJSON(@data)
    WITH (
        [from] datetime '$.from',
        [to] datetime '$.to',
        [forecast] int '$.intensity.forecast',
        [actual] int '$.intensity.actual',
        [index] nvarchar(5) '$.intensity.index'
    );
```

Comment: Can you provide an [mre]? The JSON in your question *is* valid (though the query does not return any results, which is expected for that JSON): [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c776d1f462bbcd9a755c68641d165f3)

Comment: For the given JSON you probably want `FROM OPENJSON(@data, '$.data')` but the next problem you'll hit are the invalid date formats for the `from` and `to` properties.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlwaysLearning, This is one of the options I had already tried. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

As it was already mentioned by @AlwaysLearning in the comments, JSON has datetime values in a questionable format. That's why a slight massaging was necessary.

Also, I used the `DATETIMEOFFSET(3)` data type to preserve a time zone.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        [from] DATETIMEOFFSET(3),
        [to] DATETIMEOFFSET(3),
        [forecast] int,
        [actual] int,
        [index] nvarchar(5)
);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX) =
N'{
    "data": [
        {
            "from": "2021-09-22T23:00Z",
            "to": "2021-09-22T23:30Z",
            "intensity": {
                "forecast": 105,
                "actual": 91,
                "index": "low"
            }
        },
        {
            "from": "2021-09-22T23:30Z",
            "to": "2021-09-23T00:00Z",
            "intensity": {
                "forecast": 92,
                "actual": 80,
                "index": "low"
            }
        },
        {
            "from": "2021-09-23T22:00Z",
            "to": "2021-09-23T22:30Z",
            "intensity": {
                "forecast": 153,
                "actual": null,
                "index": "low"
            }
        },
        {
            "from": "2021-09-23T22:30Z",
            "to": "2021-09-23T23:00Z",
            "intensity": {
                "forecast": 150,
                "actual": null,
                "index": "low"
            }
        }
    ]
}';

INSERT INTO @tbl ([from], [to], [forecast], [actual], [index])
SELECT LEFT([from],16) + ':00Z', LEFT([to],16) + ':00Z', [forecast], [actual], [index]
FROM OPENJSON(@data, '$.data')
WITH (
    [from] VARCHAR(30) '$.from',
    [to] VARCHAR(30) '$.to',
    [forecast] int '$.intensity.forecast',
    [actual] int '$.intensity.actual',
    [index] nvarchar(5) '$.intensity.index'
);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------+--------+-------+
| ID |              from              |               to               | forecast | actual | index |
+----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------+--------+-------+
|  1 | 2021-09-22 23:00:00.000 +00:00 | 2021-09-22 23:30:00.000 +00:00 |      105 | 91     | low   |
|  2 | 2021-09-22 23:30:00.000 +00:00 | 2021-09-23 00:00:00.000 +00:00 |       92 | 80     | low   |
|  3 | 2021-09-23 22:00:00.000 +00:00 | 2021-09-23 22:30:00.000 +00:00 |      153 | NULL   | low   |
|  4 | 2021-09-23 22:30:00.000 +00:00 | 2021-09-23 23:00:00.000 +00:00 |      150 | NULL   | low   |
+----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak, this also really helped, and worked in the example you submitted, but as soon as I try and convert your code to receiving the JSON from the Node-Red JSON payload, I'm back to square one!

DECLARE \@data NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{{{payload}}}';

RequestError: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'o' is found at position 1.

Comment: JSON is just a  text. You can examine it, and programmatically remove any 'bad' characters just before you use it in T-SQL.

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak, That I do understand, but I think what we have established on this thread is, the SQL side of this works, when we embed the raw JSON text into the SQLServer node, so the issue lies in processing the JSON text received from the API so it inserted into the SQL node in an acceptable manner.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I'm going to focus this on Node-Red now.

Comment: Additionally, you can always check if the JSON is legit via T-SQL: `SELECT ISJSON(@json)`

Comment: Again, @AndiMcBurnie , provide a [mre]. The data *you* provided in the question is **valid**. If you have invalid JSON, then you need to supply invalid JSON; or better yet fix the process that is supplying invalid JSON in the first place.